# Does AWS ELB support wildcard ports?

Tags: amazon-elb

In Azure, the Standard LB can listen on all ports and can therefore be used to load balance firewalls. This is the feature ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-ha-ports-overview ).

Does AWS have anything like this?

Comment: What kind of firewall are you wanting to load balance?  ELBs (classic, application, and network) are each intended for specific types of ingress traffic, and there aren't many cases for a wildcard listener that come to mind.

Comment: Any kind of L3 transparent devices. Could be FW, IPS, etc